# Relation between the volume and surface

Tags: geometric-construction

Is it possible to have an infinite volume of revolution of the geometric body
and in the same time its finite surface area?

With Respect,

Oleg Yovanovich

Comment: Even if you remove the restriction that it be a volume of revolution, the answer is no: [Infinite Volume but Finite Surface Area](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708571/infinite-volume-but-finite-surface-area)

Comment: For the contrary, see Gabriel's Horn:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn