# How to prove an object $\in R^3$ with its surface area finite must also have its volume finite?

Tags: calculus, continuity, improper-integrals, volume, surface-integrals

> Suppose that $f(x)>0$ is a continuously differentiable function defined on $x\ge 1$. Let $S$ be the surface of revolution of the graph $y=f(x)$ about $x-axis$. Let $E \subset  R^3$ be the solid enclosed by $S$ and $x=1$. More precisely:$$E=\left \{ (x,y,z)\in R^3;x\ge 1 \space and \space \sqrt[]{y^2+z^2}\le f(x) \space for \space each \space x\ge 1 \right \}. $$
> If the surface area of $S$ is finite, prove that the volume of $E$ must also be finite.

I have already known that the surface area of $S$ is... $$A=2\pi\int_{1}^{\infty }f(x) \sqrt[]{1+\left ( f'{(x)} ^2\right )  } dx =\lim_{b \to \infty}2\pi\int_{1}^{b} f(x) \sqrt[]{1+\left ( f'{(x)} ^2\right )  } dx$$
and the volume of $E$ is...$$V=\pi\int_{1}^{\infty } \left ( f(x) \right ) ^2dx=\lim_{b \to \infty } \pi\int_{1}^{b} \left ( f(x) \right ) ^2dx$$
Can I solve this question by the following?

$$\because \space f'(x) \space is \space continuous \space  ,\space \therefore \exists M, \space \space such \space that \space f'(x)\ge M, \space \forall x\ge1$$
then
$$A=\lim_{b \to \infty}2\pi\int_{1}^{b} f(x) \sqrt[]{1+\left ( f'{(x)} ^2\right )  } dx\ge \lim_{b \to \infty}2\pi\int_{1}^{b} f(x) \sqrt[]{1+M ^2  } dx = \lim_{b \to \infty}2\pi \sqrt[]{1+M ^2} \int_{1}^{b} f(x) dx$$
Since $A$ is finite, so $\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{1}^{b} f(x) dx$ is also finite.......$(1)$

Also:$$\because \space f(x) \space is \space continuous \space  ,\space \therefore \exists L\ge 0, \space \space such \space that \space f(x)\le L , \space \forall x\ge1$$

So...$$V=\lim_{b \to \infty } \pi\int_{1}^{b} \left ( f(x) \right ) ^2dx \le \lim_{b \to \infty } \pi\int_{1}^{b} L \times f(x)  dx = \pi L \lim_{b \to \infty } \int_{1}^{b}  f(x)  dx  ......(2)$$
Finally, because (1) tell me that $\lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{1}^{b} f(x) dx$ is finite, then I have (2) also finite?

Comment: Your two $\therefore$ (for the existence of such $M$ and $L$) are wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a shape with infinite volume but finite surface area?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708571/is-there-a-shape-with-infinite-volume-but-finite-surface-area)

Comment: Madam, I've seen the link you suggested, and I've also read the proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_horn, but there is something I haven't figure it out yet. It says $\lim_{t  \to \infty} \sup_{x\\\ge t} f(x)^2-f(1)^2=\lim_{t \to \infty} \sup \int_{1}^{t}\left ( f(x)^2 \right )'dx\le \int_{1}^{\infty } \left | (f(x)^2)' \right |dx   =\int_{1}^{\infty } 2f(x)\left | f'(x) \right | dx \le \int_{1}^{\infty } 2f(x)\sqrt[]{1+f'(x)^2}dx=\frac{A}{\pi } < \infty $, and according to this, there exists a $t _0$ such that the supremum $\sup\left \{f(x);x\ge t_0\right \}   $  is finite.

Comment: hence, it claims, $M=\sup \left \{ f(x);x\ge 1 \right \} $ must be finite, since f is a continuous function, which implies that $f$ is bounded on the interval [1, ∞)

Comment: I know  $\int_{1}^{\infty } \left | (f(x)^2)' \right | dx\ge \int_{1}^{\infty } (f(x)^2)'dx$, but WHY $\int_{1}^{\infty } \left | (f(x)^2)' \right | dx\ge \lim_{t \to \infty} \sup  \int_{1}^{t } (f(x)^2)'dx$, why we take $limsup$ here?

Comment: And it says $\sup\left \{f(x);x\ge t_0\right \}$ is finite, $M=\sup \left \{ f(x);x\ge 1 \right \}$ also finite, but is there any possible that $f(x)$ goes to $\infty$ somewhere between $\left ( 1,t_0 \right ) $?

Comment: 1) $\int_1^t (f(x)^2)'dx\le\int_1^t\left | (f(x)^2)' \right | dx\le\int_{1}^{\infty }\left | (f(x)^2)' \right | dx$ for all $t$ and the final upper bound does not depend on $t$ hence it is also an upper bound for $\limsup_{t\to\infty}\int_1^t (f(x)^2)'dx.$ 2) On $[1,t_0],$ $f$ is continuous hence bounded.

Comment: Thank you so much madam, though I'm not sure if I can understand the idea of limsup or liminf easilyQQ

Comment: $\limsup_{t\to\infty}g(t):=\lim_{t\to\infty}h(t)$ for $h(t):=\sup_{x\ge t}g(x).$ The limit exists because $h$ is non-increasing.